# How to rewrite /?custom_ref= with /?ref= using htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite

/?custom_ref=

with

/?ref=

using htaccess rewrite???

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} custom_ref=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /?ref=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Can you please tell me the directory/file that you using this query on so I make sure this code will only work with it.